# How to get same type of parameterzied values in Controller through razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop, model-view-controller

**SCENARIO:**
I have two drop-downs, As soon as I click the submit button, It needs to get two int value of "UserTableId" in the constructor,

**Problem:**
I am unable to understand how should I write them so that I can get values from the drop-downs.

**Create/View**

```
 <div class="form-group  row">
  <label>User Id</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.DropDownList("UserTableId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn  btn-primary" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTable.User_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
          </div>



<div class="form-group  row">
 <label>User Id</label> 
    <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DropDownList("UserTableId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn  btn-primary"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTable.User_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ShowAllDetail(int UserTableId,int UserTableId)     //how should I pass the same parameter or whats the solution????
    {...............}
```

UserTable DbTable
[image: UserTable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you marked your question as **MVC**, you could be using Model binding in your View with:

```
@model SomePOCOModel
```

And then use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.UserTableId1, Model.UserTable),
                    "--Select User--",
                    new { @class = "btn  btn-primary" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.UserTableId2, Model.UserTable),
                    "--Select User--",
                    new { @class = "btn  btn-primary" })
```

When loading your View pass the Model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   SomePOCOModel myModel = new SomePOCOModel();
   //Set the property UserTable to an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> 
   //built using your DB user table
   return View("Index", myModel);
}
```

And your View Model:

```
public class SomePOCOModel()
{
    public int UserTableId1 {get; set;}
    public int UserTableId2 {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserTable {get; set;}
}
```

And finally your controller post method, change to accept the model type
bound to your View:

```
//Accept the model type bound to your View
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //Use this if placing an antiforgery token in your form
public ActionResult ShowAllDetail(SomePOCOModel myModel)
{
   //Do something with the drop down selections
   //myModel.UserTableId1
   //myModel.UserTableId2
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this, the values are coming from database.. and it named as UserTableId

Comment: If we use this, this error appears.... There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UserTableId1'.

Comment: @MusaMVC You're welcome. Have a good day!